# Mysql Charset set in header, results differ on pages

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

I am building a Mysql database, holding details of owners and breeders of ponies, as well as details on the animals themselves. The information is updated and viewed via PHP. As part of this, I have pages where contacts are listed out, and other pages where contacts may be assigned (via dropdown) to an animal as either an owner or a breeder. The database connection is set in the header (called by function) and closed at the end of each query.

I noticed that some characters (e.g. É) were not being rendered properly (�) in the dropdown lists of contacts, but were fine in the list pages. Having looked into previous questons posed here ([Special characters in PHP / MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633762/special-characters-in-php-mysql)) I set my table's collation to utf8_bin, and connect to the db via

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("db", $con);
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);
?>
```

This resolved the dropdown list issue perfectly - but the list pages are now causing trouble. (É is now Ã‰). My browser was set to Western ISO-8859-1, but even changing that to UTF-8 has not helped. Echoing out

```
$charset = mysql_client_encoding($con);
echo "The current character set is: $charset\n";
```

at the foot of the list returns uft8, as it should. My bam is boozled.

Any advice greatly appreciated!

(P.s. in anticipation: the language will be overwhelmingly English, but with some Irish Gaelic, and possibly some French & German too. I have also tried all of the above with the Latin1 encoding.)

**EDIT:**

To fix the problem:

- set the charset for the connection ($con)
- set the collation for the data in the table - *by column*, by table is not sufficient
- made sure to declare the HTML charset in my header via meta tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you list display code utf8-encodes the HTML somehow. Remove that `utf8_encode` calls there.

You might also be missing the encoding declaration in the HTML pages themselves, which is needed to tell the browser that the page has the specific charset.

Comment: You mean I need to specify the charset within the html of the list itself?

Comment: ....but then my dropdowns wont read correctly. Thats my problem - if I fix one, the other breaks! Do you suggest setting the charset locally (per page) rather than in the header?

Comment: I've also set the charset per column in my table, not just table-wide.

Comment: Then you are missing the encoding specification in your HTML file.

Comment: Yep - `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>` in the header did the trick. I didnt realise it needed specifying there also! Thanks cweiske!