# PHP - File get contents and proper encoding

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I'm struggeling with a tiny script which is responsible for 2 things:
- truncating database
- uploading files into database

Looks like that:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');


$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_username = 'x';
$mysql_password = 'y';
$mysql_database = 'z';

$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$mysql_database.';host='.$mysql_host,$mysql_username,$mysql_password);

// works not with the following set to 0. You can comment this line as 1 is default
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);

function truncate_db()
{
    global $db;

    $sql_query_1 = "
    TRUNCATE TABLE `VISITS`; 
    TRUNCATE TABLE `ANIMALS`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `DOCTORS`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `PAYMENTS`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `CUSTOMER`
    "; 

    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql_query_1);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "Truncate action - OK";
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
}

function import_db()
{
    global $db;

    try
       {
         $sql_query_2 = implode(array_map(function ($v) {
            return file_get_contents($v);
            }, glob(__DIR__ . "/*.sql")));

         $qr = $db->exec($sql_query_2); 
         echo "Import action - OK";
       }
       catch (PDOException $e) 
       {
         echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

truncate_db();
echo '<br />';
import_db();

$db = null;
?>
```

Issue - files (sql one) which I'm uploading to the database contains special charaters (like ś, ó, ę etc.) After that I have an issue in the database that some of the words doesn't contain any more those symbols. After upload I have symbols like: ³, ¿ etc. How can I edit function import_db() to keep those characters? i thought about:

```
mb_convert_encoding
```

but I have no clue how to incorporate that into my code ;/ in my DB table, column with that words (containing special characters) is set to: UTF8_General_CI. thanks!

Comment: try adding: $dbh = new PDO('mysql:charset=utf8mb4');

Comment: try this - $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$mysql_database.';host='.$mysql_host,$mysql_username,$mysql_password;charset=utf8);

Comment: not working. When I use your code OR $db->exec('SET NAMES utf8'); it just cut-off everything in the word after that special character :(

Comment: Can you please tell, where did you write  $db->exec('SET NAMES utf8');?

Comment: please check this link for all possible options, I hope this will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002822/pdo-and-utf-8-special-characters-in-php-mysql

Comment: I've placed it just after: $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$mysql_database.';host='.$mysql_host,$mysql_username,$mysql_password);

Comment: Let me know if that link helped you?

Comment: @SachinVairagi - partially yes :) the only issue now is.. my files which I'm uploading must be converted into UTF8 w/o BOM. Is there any easy way in php how to convert it before upload?

Comment: @JuliaGalden , I don't understand why do you want to convert file into UTF8? can you please tell what is your basic issue and desired output?

Comment: Why upload a file to the database, instead just upload the file to the server and then store the path to it into the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unclear on what your problem is

**Truncated text** is when you try to insert `Señor`, but find that only `Se` shows up in the table.  This form of truncation is usually caused by

- The client had accented characters encoded in latin1 (or latin2, etc), and
- `SET NAMES utf8` was in effect during the `INSERT` (or `LOAD DATA`)

That is, you should either get the text in utf8 or you should change what you tell MySQL the encoding is.

If you can get the hex of the file contents, `ś ó ę` should be 2-byte hex `C59B C3B3 C499` in utf8.  latin1 only has `ó` as a single byte `F3`.  In latin2, those are `B6 F3 EA`, so perhaps that is where you are coming from?

It is OK to have a mismatch between what `SET NAMES` says and what `CHARACTER SET` you have established to table/column.  MySQL will convert the encoding as they are transferred.

Do not use `mb_convert_encoding` or any other conversion functions when using MySQL, it only adds to the confusion.

Also, do the `TRUNCATEs` one at a time.  The API does not like multiple statements.