# How to insert special language characters in PHP into MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

I am using latest PHP and latest MySQL.
I have tried htmlspecialchars and mysql_real_escape_string but it inserts ? instead of the special character.
I am inserting into varchar and text type fields. Special language characters like őúáűăţşîâ but it maight be other languages' characters.

Comment: What are you trying to insert??

Comment: Every character is special in its own way.

Comment: What character are you trying to insert...   It sounds like a collation issue.   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Special characters in PHP / MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/633762)

Comment: i make *everything* utf8, and then all is well.

Comment: What encoding are you using for your MySQL table (UTF-8, etc.)?  What encoding are you using for the data coming from PHP?

Comment: What collation are you using for your tables and in what language is the text that you are trying to save it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the default encoding for your server, your meta-tag encoding declaration, and your collation on your database and tables are. You may want to make sure that everything is set to UTF8 if you're going to have lots of language characters.