# Http Client returning null after signing the APK

Tags: android, http, jar-signing, android-keystore

I am developing an android application which uses web services that has https protocol in its url.

And I'm doing a GET request to that service.

The strange part is when I compile my android apk with debug keystore the webservice is returning expected results and when I sign my apk with release keystore the webservice is always returning me error with null message.

Please help me on this.

More Info:

- The url parameter contains Korean words
- UTF-8 Encoding is followed
- I'm using keytool for signing process
- I didn't zipalign it

Answer (score -1):

What are you using to sign it? The wizard from inside eclipse? Have you tried to create a different key?

Comment: I am using Keytool to sign it

Comment: I created Keystore from command prompt. Yes i Tried with another key and it doesn't work

Comment: you could try to do it with the eclipse wizard. what do you mean also that the url parameter contains korean words? korean characters? urls always contain out of latin characters only.

Comment: The GET request param contains Korean Characters

Comment: most probably it is an encoding issue. you will have to define something else than UTF-8. Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430982/read-non-english-characters-from-http-get-request

Comment: This is not an answer. Should have been a comment.

Comment: the answer is in my comment above before you downvoted. thanks police. :P