# PHP query not returning all COLUMNS from SELECT statement

Tags: php, sql

```
require_once ('../configuration/data_conn.php');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$sql = "
    SELECT  

    product.id,
    product.name,
    product.code,
    product.supplier,
    product.date_created,
    product.total

    FROM product";

$req_sql = $conn->prepare($sql);
$req_sql ->execute();
$data_sql = $req_sql ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($data_sql);
```

I got only 3 fields :

```
[0] => Array
   (
    [id] => 1511
    [name] => mirror
    [code] => CD-13480

  )
[1] => Array
   (
    [id] => 1512
    [name] => chair
    [code] => CD-13481

  )
```

but when i use the same query in my database tool it works.

Im sure i have access to all these columns and i use in my php connection the same credentials to login to my database.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you preparing a query that has no parameters and you only want to run once?

Comment: Remove `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and test again.

Comment: Why would removing `FETCH_ASSOC` be the problem here @JustOnUnderMillions?

Comment: @RiggsFolly the OP may be on the way to creating a function which will run all of their queries. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The same problem with FETCH_ASSOC.

Comment: Did you also check for errors after the query with `show warnings`?

Comment: Is there data in the missing columns?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard OK, right, then he should do a simply `SELECT *`. And better help, instead of .....whatever

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions It recovers nothing like error.

Comment: @AdamForbis yeah i have a data in all columns.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have already tested select *, it returns just data of 3  first columns.It's the same prob

Comment: turn logging in mysql on and lookup the mysql error logs. im out:)

Comment: Is it possible that the code column holds HTML characters?

Comment: If you alias the columns do the names change?

Comment: And better help @JustOnUnderMillions?

Comment: @Chris It doesen't the problem of character nor connector of the base because I already tested with another request and it works, I copied paste in a new page and it does not work yet, it not a problem of connector nor my code php.

Comment: @AdamForbis yeah the names change but always the same problem.

Comment: If you change your print_r to var_dump does anything change? Have you tried your query with mysqli instead of pdo?

Comment: @AdamForbis when i use var_dump it returns NULL for the 3 last columns.

Comment: But it it does show the keys?

Comment: [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "1511"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "mirror"
    ["code"]=>
    string(8) "CD-13480"
    ["supplier"]=>
    NULL
    ["date_created"]=>
    NULL
    ["total"]=>
    NULL
  }

Comment: Do you think this has any relation to your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752938/php-and-mysql-query-returns-null-on-column-with-values

Comment: @AdamForbis Thanks a lot, it's a prob of special characters of my field.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the column supplier that contains special characters, I added type char for this field and it works now.

```
    $sql = "
          SELECT  
          product.id,
          product.name,
          product.code,
          product.supplier :: char(100),
          product.date_created,
          product.total

    FROM product";
```

Thanks for your help.