# PHP and MySQL Delivering Worlds Langs as Question Marks

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have to store the text that can be in any language. So I set my mysql table to be `ucs2_unicode_ci`, it is succesuflly holding russian and chineese:

[image]

However my php page when fetching it, is delivering it as question marks.

[image]

I tried in my php file to set content-type to all kinds of things with no success:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Special characters in PHP / MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633762/special-characters-in-php-mysql)

Comment: Did you set the character set in the DB driver you are using?

Comment: Thanks @chris85 can you please help me understand that, I'm using phpmyadmin.

Comment: I don't know which driver you are using. Take a look at this thead...

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utf8mb4 would be much better than ucs2.  But, assuming you stick with ucs2, you need to establish `ucs2` for the connection.  See the advice on `set_charset` or `SET NAMES`, depending on your client.  Or, at least change `character_set_results` to `ucs2` so that it knows to covert from ucs2 to utf8 when retrieving data.

I've seen hundreds of ways the get messed up characters; this is the first time I've seen this technique.  (But, almost no one uses ucs2.)

Comment: Thanks very much for this information! Can you please explain what I would have to do if I used `utf8mb4`. The solution for me was taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/633788/1828637 . What I did was  `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn)` worked for me when I was using `ucs2_unicode_ci` on my mysql table field. Is this an unusual/quirky fix for this from your experience?

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` interface, switch to `mysqli_*`.

Comment: utf8, utf8mb4, and ucs2 are 3 different "character sets".  The corresponding "collations" for each begin with the character set name.  So, `ucs2_unicode_ci` applies to `ucs2`, `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` applies to `utf8mb4`, etc.

Comment: chris85 points to a document about utf8 all the way through.  It apples to utf8mb4, changing only the name.  Study that, then let's discuss details.

Comment: Thanks very much @RickJames Im loaded with some work right now but as soon as I read/research may i post comment here  (in like a week or so or whenever?) and we can do SO chat or in comments here please? :)

Comment: I'll probably be around to comment/chat.  I have an [unfinished blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll) on character set issues.  Your issue is almost novel enough for me to add it to the blog.

Comment: Loving it hahah "he computer world realizes that there are other people in the world...."

Comment: I recognize the arrogance and insularism in my fellow-countrymen.  And I like to pepper anything I write with at least one chuckle.

Comment: Haha plus rep for that recognition if you're countrymen are Americans :P Mine are too :P I was apart of that group when i fell prey to googles advertising :P