# php - query from mysql and display data with incorrect special characters à è ì ò ù

Tags: php, mysql, character

In my php page I read data from mysql by SQL query. In the output there are many words with special characters for example: à è ì ò ù ', but when output of query is displayed on the page, in all browsers, view a incorrect character �.

I try to use a replace function in the query

```
replace(field_name, 'à','&agrave;')
```

but not work.

If run the query in mysql, the output is correct.

How to resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have your provided to MYSQL the encoding you are using in your web application ? How do you get your result ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have resolve with this code in header of page:

<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
 ?> 
  
    <meta charset="utf-8">

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with this code insiede tag `<header> </header>`

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'); ?> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Another way to resolve this is using MYSQL to update the encoding of the web application :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "db");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

From `Stefan Gehrig` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/633826/4751603

Comment: @Gangai Johann thanks. With this answare I have resolved the incorrect character problem inside an xls export.